# Read binary file by parts

Tags: r

Is there a way how to read binary file into R by parts?

With readBin you can specify the number of records to be read, but is it possible to read records at specific positions?

I need to read and analyze large file with limited PC memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `seek()` function, just as you would in a C program.

Make a test file:

```
> cat(LETTERS,file="letters.txt")
```

See what it is - upper case with space sep:

```
> system("cat letters.txt") # unix only
 A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
```

Open:

```
> con = file("letters.txt","rb")
```

Go somewhere and read a few:

```
> seek(con,3)
[1] 0
> readBin(con,"raw",10)
 [1] 20 43 20 44 20 45 20 46 20 47
```

Those are ASCII codes. Go somewhere else and read a few more:

```
> seek(con,7)
[1] 13
> readBin(con,"raw",10)
 [1] 20 45 20 46 20 47 20 48 20 49
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but I was not able to make it work. How should I read, let's say segment of length 100 bytes starting at position 200 from the file?

Comment: E.g. `con <- file("myfile", "rb");seek(con, 200L);readBin(con, "raw", n = 100L);close(con)`?