# How can I read only specified bytes of a connection in R?

Tags: r

I have some large flat binary files (that represent raster images) that I'm trying to analyze in R. I want to be able to extract specific pixel values without having to load the entire file into memory. How can I read only the nth byte of a file in R? It doesn't seem that readBin() has this capability... I can do readBin(n=10) to read bytes 1 to 10, but not just byte 10. Thanks!

Comment: You can move to a specific byte position of a connection using `seek`. Check out `?seek`

Comment: It may be quicker just to read all the data in in managebale chunks and keep every 10th byte and throw the rest away. Probably worth experimenting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seek() is the answer I seek. Yes thank you Allan Cameron for pointing me in the right direction. And see this exact duplicate question: [Read binary file by parts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36179598/read-binary-file-by-parts)